# SlidingMenu tutorial : getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); throws NullPointerException on new activity creation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, slidingmenu

I'm trying to do this tutorial : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

It is to make a sliding menu inside an app.

Infortunately, the

> **getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);**

is throwing a null pointer exception.

I'm a beginner in android and I've read a couple of solutions but no one seems to work correctly for me and the application still crashes when it gets to this part of the code.

There are the questions I read : 
[getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) throws NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078476/getactionbar-setdisplayhomeasupenabledtrue-throws-nullpointerexception),               [getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); throws NullPointerException on new activity creation (Google - Basic Tutorial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602953/getactionbar-setdisplayhomeasupenabledtrue-throws-nullpointerexception-on-n),
[getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); nullpointer in preferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276303/getactionbar-setdisplayhomeasupenabledtrue-nullpointer-in-preferenceactivit)

Can someone help me with this ? Apparently it deals with the Action Bar but I don't know what exactly ...

It will be really helpful, thanks!

Here is the code of the MainActivity that diplays the menu,
and below it I provide you the error log 
:

> package com.example.invite.myapplication.activities;
>
> ```
> import com.example.invite.myapplication.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
> import com.example.invite.myapplication.model.NavDrawerItem;
> import com.example.invite.myapplication.R;
>
> import com.example.invite.myapplication.frags.*;
>
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.app.Fragment;
> import android.app.FragmentManager;
> import android.content.res.Configuration;
> import android.content.res.TypedArray;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
> import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
> import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.view.Menu;
> import android.view.MenuItem;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.AdapterView;
> import android.widget.ListView;
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>     private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
>     private ListView mDrawerList;
>     private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
>
>     // nav drawer title
>     private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;×
>
>     // used to store app title
>     private CharSequence mTitle;
>
>     // slide menu items
>     private String[] navMenuTitles;
>     private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
>
>     private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
>     private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>         mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
>
>         // load slide menu items
>         navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
>
>         // nav drawer icons from resources
>         navMenuIcons = getResources()
>                 .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
>
>         mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
>         mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
>
>         navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
>
>         // adding nav drawer items to array
>         // Home
>         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
>         // Find People
>         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
>         // Photos
>         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
>         // Communities, Will add a counter here
>         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
>         // Pages
>         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
>         // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
>         navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));
>
>
>         // Recycle the typed array
>         navMenuIcons.recycle();
>
>         mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
>
>         // setting the nav drawer list adapter
>         adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
>                 navDrawerItems);
>         mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
>
>         // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
>         **getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);**
>         getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
>
>         mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
>                 R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
>                 R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
>                 R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
>         ) {
>             public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
>                 getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
>                 // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
>                 invalidateOptionsMenu();
>             }
>
>             public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
>                 getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
>                 // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
>                 invalidateOptionsMenu();
>             }
>         };
>         mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
>
>         if (savedInstanceState == null) {
>             // on first time display view for first nav item
>             displayView(0);
>         }
>     }
> ```

Here the error log :

> 06-11 02:12:24.364  25134-25134/com.example.invite.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.invite.myapplication/com.example.invite.myapplication.activities.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.invite.myapplication.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:91)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And here is the "styles.xml"

> ```
> <!--
>     Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
>     by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
> -->
> <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
>     <!--
>         Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
>         res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
>         backward-compatibility can go here.
>     -->
> </style>
>
> <!-- Application theme. -->
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
>     <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
> </style>
>
> <style name = "NoActionBar" parent = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
>     <!-- <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item> -->
>     <!-- <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item> -->
> </style>
> ```
>
> ## SOLUTION : # (hope it works for you too).
>
> It was simple finally.
>
> Just add :
>
> > requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
>
> before SetContentView(View ..).
>
> As far as I understood, this kind of forces the Activity to request
>   for an Action Bar "Action Bar please ! (?)".
>
> And set the min sdk 11 and target 17 in your manifest
>
> Here the answer that helped me finally :
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/10031400

Comment: Have you tried using the code in the answers in the linked questions? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27078529/4409409

Comment: Yes, maybe not correctly ... but I tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/27078529/3907178 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/26444771/3907178 and didn't work

Comment: You should use getSupportActionBar() instead,  and extend your class with ActionBarActivity.

Comment: @AnggrayudiH, I tried but when I do this, the app crashes even before getting to the first line of the code (+ : ActionBarActivity is put as deprecated, this doesn't mean that we should avoid using it ?)

Comment: Extend AppCompatActivity then.

Comment: What theme are you using? What's the minimum and target SDK versions?

Comment: I updated my question so as you can see my res/"styles.xml"

Answer (score 0):

After you've declared this code `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` inside your OnCreate(), you must declare some codes too in your `OnOptionItemSelected()` like this:

```
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == android.R.id.home) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainListActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to run like this

```
private ActionBar actionBar;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  actionBar = getActionBar();
        if(actionBar!=null) {
           actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the solution.

It was simple finally.

Just add :

> requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

before SetContentView(View ..).

And set the min sdk 11 and target 17 in your manifest

Here the answer that helped me finally : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10031400